# Error while specifying font for use in fit_text in python-pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

I created a program in python that replaces the text in a text box of a ppt, with data taken from an excel sheet and then saves the pptx and creates PDFs of the saved ppts.
I have used the python-pptx library to do so. I wanted it to size the font automatically so I used fit_text.

```
shape.text=name1
text_frame = shape.text_frame
text_frame.fit_text(font_family=u'Montserrat-Medium', max_size=24, bold=False, italic=False, font_file=None)
text_frame.auto_size = None
```

I have the said font installed on my computer and as far I understood the documentation, it should have been good to go.
But when I run it I am met with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Rudr875/PPTtoPDF/certs.py", line 45, in <module>
    text_frame.fit_text(font_family=u'Montserrat Medium', max_size=24, bold=False, italic=False, font_file=None)      
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pptx\text\text.py", line 88, in fit_text
    font_size = self._best_fit_font_size(
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pptx\text\text.py", line 242, in _best_fit_font_size
    font_file = FontFiles.find(family, bold, italic)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pptx\text\fonts.py", line 32, in find
    return cls._font_files[(family_name, is_bold, is_italic)]
KeyError: ('Montserrat Medium', False, False)
```

Please help. Thank you in advance.

(**Update** - All the fonts that come pre-installed with Windows like Arial, Calibri, etc. are working. Only the fonts installed later, like Montserrat, Poppins, etc. are not working.)

(**Update 2** - If I provide an absolute path to the font file then it works. But if the font file path is none value it again shows the error.)

Comment: Something with the dash in 'Montserrat-Medium' or the u-unicode modifier? The error tells you that it can't find the key `Montserrat Medium` in the dictionary, so somehow your `u'Montserrat-Medium'` gets translated to `Montserrat Medium`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ronald. I'll check and update you.

Comment: @Ronald removing the - didn't work. I also tried removing the unicode modifier but it too was of no help. I have checked the name of the font is correct.

Comment: Difficult to tell. I don't have the pptx package installed. Maybe the error message provides further clues: `File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pptx\text\fonts.py", line 32, in find`? Other fonts are working?

Comment: @Ronald Calibri and Arial are working. Have no idea why Montserrat is not even though I have the full family installed.

Comment: @Ronald I did some testing and all the pre-installed fonts are working. Fonts that were installed later are not working.

Comment: @RudrakshTyagi try adding the file extension of Montserrat Medium such as Montserrat Medium.ttf  .Have alook at this https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/txt-fit-text.html

Comment: @Prathamesh thanks for commenting. I tried adding both .otf and .ttf but none seem to resolve the error.